# Putting Nested Loops Composite Numbers in Columns

Tags: java

I have to write a program that will print out all of the composite numbers that are less than 100. I have to use nested loops to complete this program. Also, the values must be displayed in a table with 10 numbers in each column.

I have been trying this program for over a week now, and I just am completely lost, could I have some help with this?

I did the composite number part, but how exactly do you put the numbers into columns with 10 numbers in each column? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SwitchStatements {
    public static void main(String[]Args) {
     for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
               System.out.println(i);
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: It should list all the composite numbers less than 100 in a table with 5 numbers in each column.

Comment: which colomn do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 10 numbers per row (ie 10 columns total), or 10 numbers per column?

Assuming you mean a "table" in the output as something that looks roughly like this (with 5 columns in this example):

```
1  2  3  4  5 
11 12 13 14 15
```

then I think what you want to do is keep track of how many numbers you've printed on this line, and only use `System.out.println` when you've printed 10 numbers, and `System.out.print` otherwise:

```
int numbersPrinted = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            if (numbersPrinted < 9) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                numbersPrinted++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);
                numbersPrinted = 0;
            }
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

If you want the numbers to line up neatly, you can add two spaces instead of one if i is less than 10 (and therefore is only one digit).

If you actually mean you want ten numbers per column like this (again, 5 in my example instead):

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
9  10
```

then you'll need to print (number of numbers / 10 numbers per column) columns per line, so you can't print them in your nested loop like in your example. Instead, you'll need to add them to an ArrayList or similar and print them in a separate loop later:

```
ArrayList<int> numbersToPrint = new ArrayList<int>();
...
if (i % j == 0) {
    numbersToPrint.add(i);
    break;
}
...
int numbersPerRow = (numbersToPrint.size()/10);
int numbersPrinted = 0;
for (int i : numbersToPrint) {
    if (numbersPrinted < (numbersPerRow - 1)) {
...
```

and the rest of that is the same as my first example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want 10 numbers in each column, check this code. It can be done with less amount of cycles, but it will be even harder to understand.
What we do here is collecting all composite numbers to list. Fill a 2-dimensional array from that list in a strange order (not row by row as usual, but column by column). And then print it in the 3rd cycle in the usual order.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> compositeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                compositeNumbers.add(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int n = compositeNumbers.size();
    int numberOfRows = 10;
    int maxNumberOfColumns = (n / numberOfRows) + 1;

    int[][] numbers = new int[numberOfRows][maxNumberOfColumns];

    for (int j = 0; j < maxNumberOfColumns; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            int index = i + j * numberOfRows;
            if (index < n) {
                numbers[i][j] = compositeNumbers.get(index);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxNumberOfColumns; j++) {
            if (i + j * numberOfRows < n)
                System.out.print(String.format("% 3d", numbers[i][j]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You will get the nice output:

```
  4 20 33 46 58 72 85 96
  6 21 34 48 60 74 86 98
  8 22 35 49 62 75 87 99
  9 24 36 50 63 76 88 100
 10 25 38 51 64 77 90
 12 26 39 52 65 78 91
 14 27 40 54 66 80 92
 15 28 42 55 68 81 93
 16 30 44 56 69 82 94
 18 32 45 57 70 84 95
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited to fix composite calculation method.

Assuming you're looking for something like this:

```
 4    20    33    46    58    72    85    96
 6    21    34    48    60    74    86    98
 8    22    35    49    62    75    87    99
 9    24    36    50    63    76    88   100
10    25    38    51    64    77    90
12    26    39    52    65    78    91
14    27    40    54    66    80    92
15    28    42    55    68    81    93
16    30    44    56    69    82    94
18    32    45    57    70    84    95
```

The first step is to divide the problem into two parts.

1. Generate all the composite numbers from 4 to 100.
2. Display all the composite numbers in columns.

You mostly did the first part.  You had some errors in your for loop configuration.

You can hold all of the composite numbers in a List<Integer>.

You calculate the number of columns with this line:

```
    int columns = (compositeNumbers.size() + columnLength - 1)
            / columnLength;
```

Since you have to create a full line to print it, you take the composite integer at position 0, then the composite integer at position 10 (assuming 10 numbers per column). then the composite integer at position 20, and so forth, until you have created a full line.

The last few rows may not have a number in the last column.  You have to take that into account when creating a display line.

Here's the code that puts all this together.  The calculateCompositeNumbers method calculates the composite numbers.  The displayCompositeNumbers method displays the composite numbers in columns.

See how the method names tell you what they do.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CompositeOutput {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        CompositeOutput compositeOutput = new CompositeOutput();
        List<Integer> compositeNumbers = compositeOutput
                .calculateCompositeNumbers();
        System.out.println(compositeOutput.displayCompositeNumbers(
                compositeNumbers, 10));
    }

    private List<Integer> calculateCompositeNumbers() {
        List<Integer> compositeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 4; i <= 100; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            int maximum = Math.min(i / 2, 10);
            for (int j = 2; j <= maximum && !found; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    compositeNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return compositeNumbers;
    }

    private String displayCompositeNumbers(List<Integer> compositeNumbers,
            int columnLength) {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int columns = (compositeNumbers.size() + columnLength - 1)
                / columnLength;

        for (int row = 0; row < columnLength; row++) {
            int tempIndex = row;
            for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
                if (tempIndex < compositeNumbers.size()) {
                    int number = compositeNumbers.get(tempIndex);
                    builder.append(String.format("%6d", number));
                }
                tempIndex += columnLength;
            }
            builder.append(lineSeparator);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Original method for finding composite numbers is correct. And suggested `calculateCompositeNumbers` method is broken. You should also check if `i != j` to decide if `i` is composite, otherwise 5 and 7 will be considered as composite. Also you can improve it by changing `j <= 10` to `j <= Math.sqrt(i)`